# Launch camera with INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA and save pictures to different location

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I've written a code for take a picture by using camera intent with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, and save picture into another directory with

```
camera_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
```

but if I change the intent with

```
INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA
```

picture is saved inside default picture android folder. 
Is it possible to save picture into different folder with this kind of intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA  intent action cannot be used because it does not return the captured image.It can only be done with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE.